# Electrical Fire From Batteries

Tags: voltage, safety

I currently have an MP3 player powered by 4 "C" batteries, so does that mean I'm powering the unit off of 6 Volts?

Anyways, the specs on the sheet said 3.7 Volts, one of the comments said 3.7 to 5 volts.

Right now I have it hooked up and it is working flawlessly with 4 "C" batteries. Everything works nicely, sound comes out and it's great. My concern is that even though the player is working properly, is there a possibility that my setup is dangerous because I am using a higher voltage?

Should I throw a resistor on it? I wanted to throw a resistor on it, but I don't know the current draw on the mp3 player. I don't care if the MP3 player shorts out; my main concern is the safety of the setup. I know higher amperage is ok, but I read a lot of posts stating that higher voltage is no good.

Should I feel for high heat output from the back? If the item is off, do I have anything to worry about?

The MP3 player that I am using is [this one](http://dx.com/p/1-5-led-mp3-player-module-with-remote-controller-fm-usb-sd-3-7v-94814?rt=1&p=2&m=2&r=3&k=1&t=1&s=102752&u=94814).

Comment: Downvoters: care to comment?

Comment: If you use a device outside its maximum ratings, anything may happen as that is what maximum ratings are there for. If the manufacturer knows the device works with 6 or 7 V, what would keep him from printing that on the documentation and asking more money for the device? If he didn't, there is a good reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to say how bad it is without knowing what sort of regulator the circuit has, but that's clearly way over voltage and Not A Good Idea. At the very least stick to 3 batteries (4.5V if alkaline, 3.6Vish if rechargeable).

I suspect there will be a component on the back getting very hot. Whether this turns into an actual fire depends on what safety standards the Chinese manufacturer has bothered with and how lucky you are.

Comment: If the unit is off, is the circuit still dangerous?

Comment: Is there a physical power switch which disconnects the batteries? If not, then it could be. Again, it all depends on the design of the board - it *might* be safe up to 9 or 12V, but without more information we don't know.

Comment: It's a hard switch. I assume that it disconnects, but I can't be 100% certain. The problem is this is a china brand and it came with no instructions or anything, so I don't know anything about the unit. I have it currently running off of 3 batteries as you recommended, and it is working. I'm just running down the batteries now to see the time I get out of them.

Comment: @JohnathanKong If you can dismantle it enough to get a picture of the circuitboard with the chip markings readable someone might be able to ID the power chip on it and look up it's specifications.

Answer (score 2):

If the 3.7-5V remark in the comments is correct, you could safely power it with 4 rechargeable C cells since they provide 1.2V across almost the entire discharge cycle.  Alkaline batteries would be running (or trying to) it out of spec no matter what you do because their voltage drops from 1.5 to 1v as they discharge.  With 4 you're pushing 6V when they're new; with 3 you'd drop below spec at ~50% discharge, probably resulting in it shutting down.

For more detail, some [voltage vs time graphs](http://www.powerstream.com/AA-tests.htm) for alkaline/NiHM batteries under varying loads might be informative.

Comment: Right now I have the unit powering off of three batteries, and it seems to be working still. I'm more interested in the batteries producing 1.2V across the entire discharge cycle. I did read that the voltage drops during the discharge cycle, but I don't know by how much. If it's at 1.2V, that would drop my input to 3.6 which is just .1V under the recommended settings. Is that enough to sustain the unit for the entire discharge cycle? I'm running it now to see how long it lasts.

Comment: Without knowing a lot more about what exactly your device is using for power hardware that's not a question we can can answer (other than that in general stuff sold on DX uses the cheapest parts that don't fail immediately).

Comment: Thanks for the info Dan. The graph that you linked is great. Gave me a lot more information on how batteries work. As for the mp3 player, I knew it would be a poor question to answer because I don't have any specs on the unit, but you've given me a lot to research. Thanks!